# Python on Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: installation, python, downloads

How can I download and install Python on Ubuntu 13.04? I'm a newbie in Ubuntu. I've only been using Ubuntu for the last 3 days.

Comment: do you need a specific version? open the software centre and search python -- install from there. OR you can open a terminal and type `sudo apt-get install python`

Comment: @amc: no need for that. Both Python 2 and Python 3 are installed by default.

Answer (score 1):

Python is already included in the default installation media for Ubuntu 13.04. You can run Python in the terminal by typing `python` or else do it the easy way by running your Python script using IDLE. IDLE is an Integrated Development Environment for Python. IDLE 3 can be installed using the Ubuntu Software Center.